# read and jlabel set icon a image with different extension .001

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, bufferedimage

```
    File file = new File("C:\\registro_sql\\Imagens\\Livro02\\0000\\000011.001");  
BufferedImage bufferedImage = null;  
try {  
    bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(file);  
     Icon icon = (Icon) bufferedImage;  
    lblImageIcon.setIcon(icon);  
} catch (IOException ex) {  
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERRO!");  
}
```

error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
Unhandled exception type IOException

at certidoesOrganizado.executor.main(executor.java:6)
```

i have some files with extesion .001, .002, .003, but the files are just image, but i cant rename it since another software use they, but i want to use java to display that images files, any idea since the BufferedImage is not showing nothing, its just retunr a error

Answer (score 0):

The error has nothing to do with the code in the question as that shows that the `IOException` has a `try/catch` block. The error is probably produced by code not shown.

Also this statement

```
Icon icon = (Icon) bufferedImage;
```

will result in a `ClassCastException` as `BufferedImage` is not an `Icon` type.

Replace

```
lblImageIcon.setIcon(icon);
```

with

```
lblImageIcon.setIcon(new ImageIcon(bufferedImage));
```